# reCAPTCHA Selenium and Buster interaction

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I am trying to interact with reCAPTCHA frame but i cannot seem to figure out how to click the Buster extension "SOLVE" button.

[image]

The site in question is Omaze free entry portion (this is for educational purposes) :)

My code so far can click on the check box but i think i am missing selecting the correct frame to click "solve button"

This part selects the iframe that recaptcha anchor is in - clicks on it and then goes back to default content (maybe i should not go back to default content ?)

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[0])
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "recaptcha-anchor"))).click()    
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
print("Waiting for solver button to load...")
```

This is my first attempt to wait for the next frame and click the "solve" button (this didnt work)

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"//iframe[@title='reCAPTCHA']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='solver-button']"))).click()
```

This is my second attempt to wait for the next frame and click the "solve" button (this didnt work)

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[2])
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="solver-button"]'))).click()
```

I have searched everywhere and cannot seem to find a solution, i am pretty sure i am just trying to select the wrong frame but i cannot seem to understand how to identify the correct frame.

Any help would be appriciated :)

Comment: i have learned since that reCaptcha uses shadow DOM and cannot be accessed via conventional means, surely there is a workaround floating around somewhere but so far i have not found anything that works for my case.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: nope, it seems there is no solution at the moment for this since selenium isnt ment to see reCaptcha buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='button-holder help-button-holder']").click()
```

It'll click the solve button but it still won't be able to bypass reCAPTCHA, instead it'll detect you as a bot and give you the following error.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhb4H.png)

So will have to find another way to work around it.